# How to change what is shown in commit editor?

Tags: git, git-commit

When I type `git commit file.c`, `vim` is opened with something like

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# Explicit paths specified without -i or -o; assuming --only paths...
# On branch work                      <- From here ->
# Changes to be committed:
#       modified:   file.c
#
# Untracked files:
#       job.sh                        <- To here ->
```

I can tell the section I quoted is something like the output of `git status`. How can it be changed? I want it to show `git diff file.c`. Can it be done? If yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `git commit -v`. Option [`-v|--verbose`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--v) does exactly that.

If you always want to see the diff configure your repository (or global):

```
git config [--global] commit.verbose true
```